# Ubuntu 20.04 - SSH Terminal launcher for many servers

Tags: command-line, ssh, launcher

I use Ubuntu 20.04, and connect to many servers by SSH terminal. Previously I used a desktop launcher from the left hand launcher.  This launcher was in my .local/share/applications folder.  I could right click on the launcher and it would show me a list of my servers that I could connect to.  There must be many people like me having to log into multiple servers.  What's the current "best" way?  Maybe some extension like the "places" dropdown on Ubuntu 20.04 / Gnome extensions.

That launcher of mine looked like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Remote Servers
Comment=Login to my servers
GenericName=shell
Keywords=shell;terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=utilities-terminal
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=RemoteServers
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Local;{many servers;...};

[Local Shortcut Group]
Name=SSH into localhost
Exec=gnome-terminal
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[SomeServer Shortcut Group]
...
```

Comment: This might possibly help:  https://askubuntu.com/a/704780/231142

Comment: No that's an odd one, I'm not sure I would frequently want to send the same commands to multiple servers.  I think my problem stems to ```X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts```

Comment: Okay - I've discovered "Profiles" in the terminal.  I've not solved the problem but I'm over it.

Comment: You don't have to send the same command to all windows that are open, but it is sure convenient to allow you to open as many windows as you want with one run.  That is actually what I use it for since I work around thousands of servers everyday.  It honestly has made my life easier, especially if you have to use a "bastion" type server to connect to other servers or if you have to use a tunnel, etc.