# call multiple functions in multiple terminals

Tags: command-line, bash

I am defining a function in my `.bashrc` that I am using to call multiple other functions.

```
function startday {
    irene 
}
```

This works, (`irene` is a function defined and sourced)
However, I want to execute this in another terminal.

```
function startday {
    gnome-terminal -c "irene"
}
```

says `Failed to execute child process "irene" (No such file or directory)`

`irene` activates a virtualenv, so I want the terminal to not exit after running the command.
(Needless to say simply executing `irene` on the terminal does execute the function successfully.)

Comment: Would this: http://askubuntu.com/a/642095/72216 work for you?

Comment: Maybe just write a script that does the job? The function will not be defined in the new shell, you would have to source/define it again. But I think it would be easier to write a script and just run `gnome-terminal -c "~/scripts/irene.sh"`

Answer (score 1):

On my version of gnome terminal

```
$ gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.22.0
```

I do not have option `-c`, but instead I have option `-x` or `-e`

However if you want to start `gnome-terminal` running internal function *sourced* in .bashrc you may try to do it this way:

```
gnome-terminal -x "bash" -ic "irene"
```

**Please note** that bash's `-i` option will make sure that your `.bashrc` is evaulated, therefore `irene` function is available.

**Please also note**, that after `irene` function finishes its operation, `gnome-terminal` will stop. You may consider running some commands **after** `irene`, like for example:

```
gnome-terminal -x "bash" -ic "irene; sleep 2;" # wait 2 seconds after "irene" stops
```

or

```
gnome-terminal -x "bash" -ic "irene; bash;" # run NEW instance of bash after "irene" stops
```

If irene function sets some environmental variables, they may be accessible in this NEW instance of bash **only if you export** them.

```
function irene() {
   # ...some code
   export variable="value of variable"
   # ...some code
}
```

instead of

```
function irene() {
   # ...some code
   variable="value of variable"
   # ...some code
}
```