# How do I get xdotool to register a new gnome-terminal window?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, window-manager, alias

I'm trying to create an alias that I can run from `guake` that will open a new window, make it fullscreen, and run `pipes.sh`. Currently, I have everything but the new window accomplished:

```
xdotool key F11 && clear && pipes.sh [long list of options] && exit
```

However, when I wrap that in a `gnome-terminal` command:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c "xdotool key F11 && clear && pipes.sh [long list of options] && exit; bash"
```

It makes the terminal that I run the command from go fullscreen, executing the rest in a new terminal window behind it. Is there a way to get `xdotool` to generate the keystroke in the new terminal?

EDIT: I've narrowed it down to this:

```
title=$(echo -ne "\033]0;Screensaver\007"; xdotool search --name "Screensaver" key F11); pipes=$($title && clear && pipes.sh -p 5 -t 3 -f 100 -s 15 -r 500 -R && exit); term=$(gnome-terminal -x sh -c "$pipes"; bash); echo "$term"
```

However, it pops up with an error afterwards that I can't seem to fix (`: command not found`). Any thoughts?

Comment: It works OK for me.  The command beginning with the `gnome-terminal` should have opened a new window and ran the command in it.  I guess you could always try if this command works for you:  `gnome-terminal -e 'sh -c "xdotool key F11 && clear && pipes.sh [long list of options] && exit; bash"'`

Comment: @Terrance It opens it in a new window, but the issue is that xdotool outputs the key to the original window instead of the new window.

Comment: I'm just telling you what is working for me here.  Try executing it from a different type of terminal like `xfce4-terminal` then running your `gnome-terminal` command so that you can see.  Unfortunately, xdotool is not running in my original terminal at all with the gnome-terminal command in the beginning.  If I run the xdotool at the beginning of the command then yes, it does run in my original window.

Comment: @Terrance Can you see anything wrong with the command now?

Comment: Not sure I understand cotrrectly, but see https://askubuntu.com/questions/641683/how-can-i-send-commands-to-specific-terminal-windows. If it s what you are looking for, I will edit to make it full screen.

Comment: @JacobVlijm That... might just work, actually.

Comment: Cool, I will add a little edit tonight late.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I've got my alias edited (`target_term -set 1 && target_term -run 1 "xdotool key F11 && clear && pipes.sh -p 5 -t 3 -f 100 -s 15 -r 5000 -R && exit"`), but it's throwing errors on line 46 (`IndexError: list index out of range`)

Comment: @Creep2DJ it turns out the process name of gnome-terminal changed since the time I created the script. edited/updated. Now it works fine again. Let me know if you manage.